# Issue with Swiping to Close PageView.builder in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm currently working on a Flutter app where I have a PageView.builder wrapped in a Stack. I want to implement the functionality where if the user is on the first page of the PageView.builder and swipes right, the page should be closed. However, I've been facing difficulties in getting the swipe gestures to work as expected.

I've tried using a NotificationListener and a GestureDetector, but I'm not getting the desired behavior. The swipe gestures are not being detected as intended. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SwipeClosePageView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SwipeClosePageViewState createState() => _SwipeClosePageViewState();
}

class _SwipeClosePageViewState extends State<SwipeClosePageView> {
  final PageController _pageController = PageController();
  final int _totalPages = 5;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Swipe to Close PageView'),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          PageView.builder(
            controller: _pageController,
            itemCount: _totalPages,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Center(
                child: Text('Page ${index + 1}'),
              );
            },
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onHorizontalDragEnd: (details) {
              if (details.primaryVelocity! > 0 && _pageController.page == 0) {
                Navigator.pop(context); // Close the page if on the first page
              }
            },
            child: Container(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

I've also tried using a NotificationListener to handle the swipe gestures, but the detection doesn't seem to work as expected. Could someone guide me on how to properly implement the swipe-to-close functionality for a PageView.builder when the user is on the first page in a Stack?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm getting the same issue in one of my project. so instead of using default PageViewBuilder i have created my `CustomPageViewBuilder` you can import this file in your project. also you have to use `pagecontroller` like this   `CustomPageController pageController = CustomPageController();`

```
import 'dart:math' as math;

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart'
    show clampDouble, precisionErrorTolerance;
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart' show DragStartBehavior;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

class CustomPageController extends ScrollController {
  CustomPageController({
    this.initialPage = 0,
    this.keepPage = true,
    this.viewportFraction = 1.0,
  }) : assert(viewportFraction > 0.0);

  final int initialPage;

  final bool keepPage;

  final double viewportFraction;

  double? get page {
    assert(
      positions.isNotEmpty,
      'CustomPageController.page cannot be accessed before a CustomPageView is built with it.',
    );
    assert(
      positions.length == 1,
      'The page property cannot be read when multiple CustomPageViews are attached to '
      'the same CustomPageController.',
    );
    final _PagePosition position = this.position as _PagePosition;
    return position.page;
  }

  Future<void> animateToPage(
    int page, {
    required Duration duration,
    required Curve curve,
  }) {
    final _PagePosition position = this.position as _PagePosition;
    if (position._cachedPage != null) {
      position._cachedPage = page.toDouble();
      return Future<void>.value();
    }

    return position.animateTo(
      position.getPixelsFromPage(page.toDouble()),
      duration: duration,
      curve: curve,
    );
  }

  void jumpToPage(int page) {
    final _PagePosition position = this.position as _PagePosition;
    if (position._cachedPage != null) {
      position._cachedPage = page.toDouble();
      return;
    }

    position.jumpTo(position.getPixelsFromPage(page.toDouble()));
  }

  Future<void> nextPage({required Duration duration, required Curve curve}) {
    return animateToPage(page!.round() + 1, duration: duration, curve: curve);
  }

  Future<void> previousPage(
      {required Duration duration, required Curve curve}) {
    return animateToPage(page!.round() - 1, duration: duration, curve: curve);
  }

  @override
  ScrollPosition createScrollPosition(ScrollPhysics physics,
      ScrollContext context, ScrollPosition? oldPosition) {
    return _PagePosition(
      physics: physics,
      context: context,
      initialPage: initialPage,
      keepPage: keepPage,
      viewportFraction: viewportFraction,
      oldPosition: oldPosition,
    );
  }

  @override
  void attach(ScrollPosition position) {
    super.attach(position);
    final _PagePosition pagePosition = position as _PagePosition;
    pagePosition.viewportFraction = viewportFraction;
  }
}

class PageMetrics extends FixedScrollMetrics {
  PageMetrics({
    required super.minScrollExtent,
    required super.maxScrollExtent,
    required super.pixels,
    required super.viewportDimension,
    required super.axisDirection,
    required this.viewportFraction,
    required super.devicePixelRatio,
  });

  @override
  PageMetrics copyWith({
    double? minScrollExtent,
    double? maxScrollExtent,
    double? pixels,
    double? viewportDimension,
    AxisDirection? axisDirection,
    double? viewportFraction,
    double? devicePixelRatio,
  }) {
    return PageMetrics(
      minScrollExtent: minScrollExtent ??
          (hasContentDimensions ? this.minScrollExtent : null),
      maxScrollExtent: maxScrollExtent ??
          (hasContentDimensions ? this.maxScrollExtent : null),
      pixels: pixels ?? (hasPixels ? this.pixels : null),
      viewportDimension: viewportDimension ??
          (hasViewportDimension ? this.viewportDimension : null),
      axisDirection: axisDirection ?? this.axisDirection,
      viewportFraction: viewportFraction ?? this.viewportFraction,
      devicePixelRatio: devicePixelRatio ?? this.devicePixelRatio,
    );
  }

  double? get page {
    return math.max(
            0.0, clampDouble(pixels, minScrollExtent, maxScrollExtent)) /
        math.max(1.0, viewportDimension * viewportFraction);
  }

  final double viewportFraction;
}

class _PagePosition extends ScrollPositionWithSingleContext
    implements PageMetrics {
  _PagePosition({
    required super.physics,
    required super.context,
    this.initialPage = 0,
    bool keepPage = true,
    double viewportFraction = 1.0,
    super.oldPosition,
  })  : assert(viewportFraction > 0.0),
        _viewportFraction = viewportFraction,
        _pageToUseOnStartup = initialPage.toDouble(),
        super(
          initialPixels: null,
          keepScrollOffset: keepPage,
        );

  final int initialPage;
  double _pageToUseOnStartup;

  double? _cachedPage;

  @override
  Future<void> ensureVisible(
    RenderObject object, {
    double alignment = 0.0,
    Duration duration = Duration.zero,
    Curve curve = Curves.ease,
    ScrollPositionAlignmentPolicy alignmentPolicy =
        ScrollPositionAlignmentPolicy.explicit,
    RenderObject? targetRenderObject,
  }) {
    return super.ensureVisible(
      object,
      alignment: alignment,
      duration: duration,
      curve: curve,
      alignmentPolicy: alignmentPolicy,
    );
  }

  @override
  double get viewportFraction => _viewportFraction;
  double _viewportFraction;
  set viewportFraction(double value) {
    if (_viewportFraction == value) {
      return;
    }
    final double? oldPage = page;
    _viewportFraction = value;
    if (oldPage != null) {
      forcePixels(getPixelsFromPage(oldPage));
    }
  }

  double get _initialPageOffset =>
      math.max(0, viewportDimension * (viewportFraction - 1) / 2);

  double getPageFromPixels(double pixels, double viewportDimension) {
    assert(viewportDimension > 0.0);
    final double actual = math.max(0.0, pixels - _initialPageOffset) /
        (viewportDimension * viewportFraction);
    final double round = actual.roundToDouble();
    if ((actual - round).abs() < precisionErrorTolerance) {
      return round;
    }
    return actual;
  }

  double getPixelsFromPage(double page) {
    return page * viewportDimension * viewportFraction + _initialPageOffset;
  }

  @override
  double? get page {
    assert(
      !hasPixels || hasContentDimensions,
      'Page value is only available after content dimensions are established.',
    );
    return !hasPixels || !hasContentDimensions
        ? null
        : _cachedPage ??
            getPageFromPixels(
                clampDouble(pixels, minScrollExtent, maxScrollExtent),
                viewportDimension);
  }

  @override
  void saveScrollOffset() {
    PageStorage.maybeOf(context.storageContext)?.writeState(
        context.storageContext,
        _cachedPage ?? getPageFromPixels(pixels, viewportDimension));
  }

  @override
  void restoreScrollOffset() {
    if (!hasPixels) {
      final double? value = PageStorage.maybeOf(context.storageContext)
          ?.readState(context.storageContext) as double?;
      if (value != null) {
        _pageToUseOnStartup = value;
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  void saveOffset() {
    context.saveOffset(
        _cachedPage ?? getPageFromPixels(pixels, viewportDimension));
  }

  @override
  void restoreOffset(double offset, {bool initialRestore = false}) {
    if (initialRestore) {
      _pageToUseOnStartup = offset;
    } else {
      jumpTo(getPixelsFromPage(offset));
    }
  }

  @override
  bool applyViewportDimension(double viewportDimension) {
    final double? oldViewportDimensions =
        hasViewportDimension ? this.viewportDimension : null;
    if (viewportDimension == oldViewportDimensions) {
      return true;
    }
    final bool result = super.applyViewportDimension(viewportDimension);
    final double? oldPixels = hasPixels ? pixels : null;
    double page;
    if (oldPixels == null) {
      page = _pageToUseOnStartup;
    } else if (oldViewportDimensions == 0.0) {
      page = _cachedPage!;
    } else {
      page = getPageFromPixels(oldPixels, oldViewportDimensions!);
    }
    final double newPixels = getPixelsFromPage(page);

    _cachedPage = (viewportDimension == 0.0) ? page : null;

    if (newPixels != oldPixels) {
      correctPixels(newPixels);
      return false;
    }
    return result;
  }

  @override
  void absorb(ScrollPosition other) {
    super.absorb(other);
    assert(_cachedPage == null);

    if (other is! _PagePosition) {
      return;
    }

    if (other._cachedPage != null) {
      _cachedPage = other._cachedPage;
    }
  }

  @override
  bool applyContentDimensions(double minScrollExtent, double maxScrollExtent) {
    final double newMinScrollExtent = minScrollExtent + _initialPageOffset;
    return super.applyContentDimensions(
      newMinScrollExtent,
      math.max(newMinScrollExtent, maxScrollExtent - _initialPageOffset),
    );
  }

  @override
  PageMetrics copyWith({
    double? minScrollExtent,
    double? maxScrollExtent,
    double? pixels,
    double? viewportDimension,
    AxisDirection? axisDirection,
    double? viewportFraction,
    double? devicePixelRatio,
  }) {
    return PageMetrics(
      minScrollExtent: minScrollExtent ??
          (hasContentDimensions ? this.minScrollExtent : null),
      maxScrollExtent: maxScrollExtent ??
          (hasContentDimensions ? this.maxScrollExtent : null),
      pixels: pixels ?? (hasPixels ? this.pixels : null),
      viewportDimension: viewportDimension ??
          (hasViewportDimension ? this.viewportDimension : null),
      axisDirection: axisDirection ?? this.axisDirection,
      viewportFraction: viewportFraction ?? this.viewportFraction,
      devicePixelRatio: devicePixelRatio ?? this.devicePixelRatio,
    );
  }
}

class _ForceImplicitScrollPhysics extends ScrollPhysics {
  const _ForceImplicitScrollPhysics({
    required this.allowImplicitScrolling,
    super.parent,
  });

  @override
  _ForceImplicitScrollPhysics applyTo(ScrollPhysics? ancestor) {
    return _ForceImplicitScrollPhysics(
      allowImplicitScrolling: allowImplicitScrolling,
      parent: buildParent(ancestor),
    );
  }

  @override
  final bool allowImplicitScrolling;
}

class PageScrollPhysics extends ScrollPhysics {
  const PageScrollPhysics({super.parent});

  @override
  PageScrollPhysics applyTo(ScrollPhysics? ancestor) {
    return PageScrollPhysics(parent: buildParent(ancestor));
  }

  double _getPage(ScrollMetrics position) {
    if (position is _PagePosition) {
      return position.page!;
    }
    return position.pixels / position.viewportDimension;
  }

  double _getPixels(ScrollMetrics position, double page) {
    if (position is _PagePosition) {
      return position.getPixelsFromPage(page);
    }
    return page * position.viewportDimension;
  }

  double _getTargetPixels(
      ScrollMetrics position, Tolerance tolerance, double velocity) {
    double page = _getPage(position);
    if (velocity < -tolerance.velocity) {
      page -= 0.5;
    } else if (velocity > tolerance.velocity) {
      page += 0.5;
    }
    return _getPixels(position, page.roundToDouble());
  }

  @override
  Simulation? createBallisticSimulation(
      ScrollMetrics position, double velocity) {
    if ((velocity <= 0.0 && position.pixels <= position.minScrollExtent) ||
        (velocity >= 0.0 && position.pixels >= position.maxScrollExtent)) {
      return super.createBallisticSimulation(position, velocity);
    }
    final Tolerance tolerance = toleranceFor(position);
    final double target = _getTargetPixels(position, tolerance, velocity);
    if (target != position.pixels) {
      return ScrollSpringSimulation(spring, position.pixels, target, velocity,
          tolerance: tolerance);
    }
    return null;
  }

  @override
  bool get allowImplicitScrolling => false;
}

final CustomPageController _defaultCustomPageController =
    CustomPageController();
const PageScrollPhysics _kPagePhysics = PageScrollPhysics();

class CustomPageView extends StatefulWidget {
  CustomPageView({
    super.key,
    this.scrollDirection = Axis.horizontal,
    this.reverse = false,
    CustomPageController? controller,
    this.physics,
    this.pageSnapping = true,
    this.onPageChanged,
    List<Widget> children = const <Widget>[],
    this.dragStartBehavior = DragStartBehavior.start,
    this.allowImplicitScrolling = false,
    this.restorationId,
    this.clipBehavior = Clip.hardEdge,
    this.scrollBehavior,
    this.padEnds = true,
  })  : controller = controller ?? _defaultCustomPageController,
        childrenDelegate = SliverChildListDelegate(children);

  CustomPageView.builder({
    super.key,
    this.scrollDirection = Axis.horizontal,
    this.reverse = false,
    CustomPageController? controller,
    this.physics,
    this.pageSnapping = true,
    this.onPageChanged,
    required NullableIndexedWidgetBuilder itemBuilder,
    ChildIndexGetter? findChildIndexCallback,
    int? itemCount,
    this.dragStartBehavior = DragStartBehavior.start,
    this.allowImplicitScrolling = false,
    this.restorationId,
    this.clipBehavior = Clip.hardEdge,
    this.scrollBehavior,
    this.padEnds = true,
  })  : controller = controller ?? _defaultCustomPageController,
        childrenDelegate = SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
          itemBuilder,
          findChildIndexCallback: findChildIndexCallback,
          childCount: itemCount,
        );

  CustomPageView.custom({
    super.key,
    this.scrollDirection = Axis.horizontal,
    this.reverse = false,
    CustomPageController? controller,
    this.physics,
    this.pageSnapping = true,
    this.onPageChanged,
    required this.childrenDelegate,
    this.dragStartBehavior = DragStartBehavior.start,
    this.allowImplicitScrolling = false,
    this.restorationId,
    this.clipBehavior = Clip.hardEdge,
    this.scrollBehavior,
    this.padEnds = true,
  }) : controller = controller ?? _defaultCustomPageController;

  final bool allowImplicitScrolling;

  final String? restorationId;

  final Axis scrollDirection;

  final bool reverse;

  final CustomPageController controller;

  final ScrollPhysics? physics;

  final bool pageSnapping;

  final ValueChanged<int>? onPageChanged;

  final SliverChildDelegate childrenDelegate;

  final DragStartBehavior dragStartBehavior;

  final Clip clipBehavior;

  final ScrollBehavior? scrollBehavior;

  final bool padEnds;

  @override
  State<CustomPageView> createState() => _CustomPageViewState();
}

class _CustomPageViewState extends State<CustomPageView> {
  int _lastReportedPage = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _lastReportedPage = widget.controller.initialPage;
  }

  AxisDirection _getDirection(BuildContext context) {
    switch (widget.scrollDirection) {
      case Axis.horizontal:
        assert(debugCheckHasDirectionality(context));
        final TextDirection textDirection = Directionality.of(context);
        final AxisDirection axisDirection =
            textDirectionToAxisDirection(textDirection);
        return widget.reverse
            ? flipAxisDirection(axisDirection)
            : axisDirection;
      case Axis.vertical:
        return widget.reverse ? AxisDirection.up : AxisDirection.down;
    }
  }

  int count = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final AxisDirection axisDirection = _getDirection(context);
    final ScrollPhysics physics = _ForceImplicitScrollPhysics(
      allowImplicitScrolling: widget.allowImplicitScrolling,
    ).applyTo(
      widget.pageSnapping
          ? _kPagePhysics.applyTo(widget.physics ??
              widget.scrollBehavior?.getScrollPhysics(context))
          : widget.physics ?? widget.scrollBehavior?.getScrollPhysics(context),
    );

    return NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
      onNotification: (ScrollNotification notification) {
        if (notification.depth == 0 &&
            widget.onPageChanged != null &&
            notification is ScrollUpdateNotification) {
          final PageMetrics metrics = notification.metrics as PageMetrics;
          final int currentPage = metrics.page!.round();
          print("dsffafafaf $currentPage");
          print("dsffafafaflast $count");
          if (currentPage != _lastReportedPage) {
            _lastReportedPage = currentPage;
            widget.onPageChanged!(currentPage);
          } else {
            if (currentPage == 0) {
              if (notification.metrics.outOfRange == true) {
                if (count == 0) {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  count = 0;
                }
                count++;
              }
            }
          }
        }
        return false;
      },
      child: Scrollable(
        dragStartBehavior: widget.dragStartBehavior,
        axisDirection: axisDirection,
        controller: widget.controller,
        physics: physics,
        restorationId: widget.restorationId,
        scrollBehavior: widget.scrollBehavior ??
            ScrollConfiguration.of(context).copyWith(scrollbars: false),
        viewportBuilder: (BuildContext context, ViewportOffset position) {
          return Viewport(
            cacheExtent: widget.allowImplicitScrolling ? 1.0 : 0.0,
            cacheExtentStyle: CacheExtentStyle.viewport,
            axisDirection: axisDirection,
            offset: position,
            clipBehavior: widget.clipBehavior,
            slivers: <Widget>[
              SliverFillViewport(
                viewportFraction: widget.controller.viewportFraction,
                delegate: widget.childrenDelegate,
                padEnds: widget.padEnds,
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void debugFillProperties(DiagnosticPropertiesBuilder description) {
    super.debugFillProperties(description);
    description
        .add(EnumProperty<Axis>('scrollDirection', widget.scrollDirection));
    description.add(
        FlagProperty('reverse', value: widget.reverse, ifTrue: 'reversed'));
    description.add(DiagnosticsProperty<CustomPageController>(
        'controller', widget.controller,
        showName: false));
    description.add(DiagnosticsProperty<ScrollPhysics>(
        'physics', widget.physics,
        showName: false));
    description.add(FlagProperty('pageSnapping',
        value: widget.pageSnapping, ifFalse: 'snapping disabled'));
    description.add(FlagProperty('allowImplicitScrolling',
        value: widget.allowImplicitScrolling,
        ifTrue: 'allow implicit scrolling'));
  }
}
```